# Difference between modules and shared libraries?

Tags: module, linker, shared-libraries, cmake

The title mostly covers it, what is the difference between a module and a shared library? I just found this distinction in CMake's `add_library` command, where they say:

> SHARED libraries are linked dynamically and loaded at runtime. MODULE libraries are plugins that are not linked into other targets but may be loaded dynamically at runtime using dlopen-like functionality.

But I can load a shared object using dlopen(), can't I?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The difference is that you can link to a SHARED library with the linker, but you cannot link to a MODULE with the linker. On *some* platforms.

So... to be fully cross-platform and work everywhere CMake works, you should never do this:

```
# This is a big NO-NO:
add_library(mylib MODULE ${srcs})
target_link_libraries(myexe mylib)
```

To be fair, on Windows, they're both just dlls, and so this code might actually work. But when you take it to a platform where it's impossible to link to the MODULE, you'll encounter an error.

Bottom line: if you need to link to the library, use SHARED. If you are guaranteed that the library will *only* be loaded dynamically, then it's safe to use a MODULE. (And perhaps even preferable to help detect if somebody *does* try to link to it...)

Comment: Does anyone know on which platforms this could be an issue?

Comment: > but you cannot link to a MODULE with the linker. On *some* platforms ...  

Even if they can be added as a library. Are you actually linking to it on Windows if it does not use any symbols?

Comment: The point is, if a library is a MODULE, then you should not try to link to it. You should LoadLibrary or dlopen it, and call into it dynamically. When I say later "so this code might actually work" I mean the CMake code invoking target_link_libraries. But it's a no-no with MODULE libraries, so even if it seems to "work" (more correctly, "NOT produce an error") then just don't do it.

Comment: It seems that we can always use shared library instead of module library. So why there is something called module library?

Comment: are the two target same on linux?

Answer (score 12):

I think the distinction being made is that shared libraries are specified by the developer at compile-time and must be present for the application to run, even though their methods are loaded at runtime.  A module, i.e. plugin, adds additional support at runtime but isn't required.  Yes, you can dlopen() a shared library but in that case it would not have been specified as a required part of the program and functions instead as a module.

Answer (score 7):

Another difference is in how [`..._OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) and [`..._OUTPUT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME.html) are handled:

> Module libraries are always treated as library targets. For non-DLL platforms shared libraries are treated as library targets. For DLL platforms the DLL part of a shared library is treated as a runtime target and the corresponding import library is treated as an archive target. All Windows-based systems including Cygwin are DLL platforms.

For example, this means that if you compile a `SHARED` library on Windows, `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` will be ignored, because it's looking at `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Important specific of a MODULE library is that it may use **symbols** (functions and variables) which are **not defined** in the library (and not defined in the libraries it is linked with). Such feature is very useful when create *plugins*: a plugin may call functions which are defined in the application which loads that plugin.

A regular SHARED library is not allowed to use undefined symbols.

Also, it is not allowed to link with a library, which contains not defined symbols. For that reason CMake explicitly prohibits linking with a MODULE library. And for that reason CMake doesn't create for a MODULE library additional files, which are used primarily for linking (import files on Windows, so-versions and symlinks on Linux, etc.).

---

For example, an application may allow plugins to create additional windows.

plugin.h:

```c
// Creates a window.
//
// The function is defined by the application and can be used by plugins.
void CreateWindow(const char* name);

// Initialize the plugin.
//
// Called by the application. Should be defined by the plugin itself.
void InstantiatePlugin(void);
```

cool_plugin.c:

```c
#include <plugin.h>

void InstantiatePlugin(void)
{
   // Just create two windows
   CreateWindow("Cool1");
   CreateWindow("Cool2");
}
```

Such plugin can be built with CMake by using a MODULE library:

```cmake
# CMakeLists.txt
#
add_library(cool_plugin MODULE cool_plugin.c)
target_include_directories(cool_plugin PRIVATE </path/to/directory/with/plugin.h>)
```

Would one replace MODULE with SHARED in the above code, building the plugin will fail with [undefined reference/unresolved external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) error.

Code of the application itself could look as following:

```c
// application.c
#include <plugin.h>

int CreateWindow(const char* name)
{
  // ... actually create a window.
}

int main(void)
{
   // .. Some initialization

   // ... Load the plugin in the platform-specific way (dlopen or LoadLibrary)

   void (*instantiate)(void) = ... ; // find function 'InstantiatePlugin' in the plugin

   instantiate();
}
```