# Should C packages be compiled as modules rather than shared libraries for Lua?

Tags: c, macos, lua, shared-libraries

In Lua, C packages are libraries of native code loaded from [CPATH](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.cpath). There are [two types of libraries that can be loaded dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4845984/2441747): shared libraries and modules. The difference being that shared libraries can be linked against and modules can not. The dynamic loading aspects are similar for both types, so both will load the same with Lua.

In PiL, [it's suggested](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.2.html) that shared libraries should be used. This chapter even mentions "dynamic linking" multiple times, when in my opinion, it should be "dynamic loading". Am I misinterpreting this chapter?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any definitive answer in PiL about how to build C packages correctly. To me it seems that they should be compiled as modules rather than shared libraries, because they should not be linked against. Is this assumption correct?

I first started researching this because on macOS shared libraries have to have `.dylib` extension, and modules (or "bundles" in macOS terminology), [can have **any** extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2339910/2441747), and it's a very common practice in ported software to use `.so` extension (for example, CMake defaults when targeting macOS are `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX=.dylib` and `CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_SUFFIX=.so`). Lua on macOS will only try to load libraries with `.so` extension with default CPATH.

Comment: The Lua book just doesn't use that terminology because this distinction exists pretty much only on the Apple ecosystem (in Linux and Windows there's no such difference, there are only SO's/DLLs), and even there it's not a really major difference (you can still dlopen a dylib).

Comment: I use `-o foo.so -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup` when creating C libraries for Lua that are meant to be dynamically loaded in macOS. See examples at https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/.

Comment: On Windows there's no difference, but on Linux there is, however both have `.so` extension. The difference being that shared libraries can be linked against, and modules can not. I believe this is where the term "module" is coming from, on macOS they are called "bundles".

Answer (score 0):

The PiL book you read is the first edition which was written for Lua **5.0**. In the newer edition (since 2nd) the term "C Packages" has been changed to "C **Modules**". So the answer is already very clear.

In addition, the book also provides the definition of package:

> Starting in version 5.1, Lua has defined a set of policies for modules and packages (a package being a collection of modules).

Comment: Yes, that's correct, later editions changed the terminology. However, I couldn't find any compilation instructions for them in the book.

Comment: The module system is a new feature, so I can understand why there are no compilation instructions.